# Ant mkdir failed

Tags: ant, mkdir

i'm new to ant. Please highlight which goes wrong in my build.xml. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Problem: The folders i wanted to make kept created on the upper level of current directory.

- ant version: 1.8.0
- platform: LinuxMint 10.10
- java version "1.6.0_20"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.9) (6b20-1.9.9-0ubuntu1~10.10.2)
- OpenJDK Server VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode)

build.xml:

```
<property name="prj.root"       value="." />
<property name="build.dir"      value="${prj.root}/build"/>
<property name="build.docs"     value="${build.dir}/docs"/>
<property name="build.models"   value="${build.dir}/models"/>
<property name="build.projects" value="${build.dir}/projects"/>
<property name="dist.dir"       value="${prj.root}/dist"/>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
</target>

<target name="init" depends="clean" description="initialization target">
    <echo message=">> Build JAS  ${jas.version} at ${prj.root}"/>
    <echo message="build.dir = ${build.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${build.docs}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build.models}" />
    <mkdir dir="${build.projects}" />
    <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Execution + Output:

```
yamhon@yamhon-g410 ~/projects/JAS $ ant init

Buildfile: /home/yamhon/projects/JAS/build.xml

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/yamhon/projects/build
   [delete] Deleting directory /home/yamhon/projects/dist

init:
     [echo] >> Build JAS  ${jas.version} at .
     [echo] build.dir = ./build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/yamhon/projects/build
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/yamhon/projects/build/docs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/yamhon/projects/build/models
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/yamhon/projects/build/projects
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/yamhon/projects/dist

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
yamhon@yamhon-g410 ~/projects/JAS $
```

Comment: Edit: 2011-10-02: Check the "basedir" of <project> tag of the build.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you can try.

1) Resolve your relative '.' path by assigning it to a property with the location attribute.

```
<property name="my.path" location="."/>
<echo message="my.path = ${my.path}"/>
```

2) Use the build in basedir property which points to the directory of the build.xml file itself.

```
<echo message="basedir = ${basedir}"/>
```

This should get you going :)

Comment: Thanks for advise, but I tried both and no work. Echoing basedir shows the upper directory (i.e. if my working directory is /home/yamhon/projects/JAS, and it shows /home/yamhon/projects). Any other parts I may missed? I didn't configure any ant_home/java_home or so for the "ant" command

Comment: Can you try passing -f argument to the ant with the complete path of your Build.xml file and try echoing basedir again?

Comment: `code` yamhon@yamhon-g410 ~/projects/JAS $ ant -f /home/yamhon/projects/JAS/build.xml echo
Buildfile: /home/yamhon/projects/JAS/build.xml

echo:
     [echo] basedir=/home/yamhon/projects

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second

Comment: Solution found! The "basedir" attribute of the starting <project> tag is incorrect. Now problem solved. Many thanks for help!